# Displaying a load animation during a slow page redraw

Tags: javascript, css, animation, loading, redraw

I'm working on a web application that uses JavaScript to generate a series of graphs.  This triggers a redraw that takes approximately 1 second.  I'm trying to display some sort of loading animation during the redraw to provide visual feedback and help show the user that the page has continued to function.  I've tried to add CSS animations to the page, but they freeze while the redraw takes place.  Is there any way to avoid these animations freezing during the redraw?

Comment: Do you use pure JavaScript or does generating your graph involve ajax, too?

Comment: I'm using canvases to generate images and then using the toDataURL method to create image objects.  I'm not simply using canvases because that kept causing safari to crash.

Comment: Also, no AJAX in the graph generation, all the data is stored locally.